# Loading an assembly with dependencies to other assemblies within its directory which is outside the loading applications directory?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, c++-cli, .net-assembly

I have an application which say runs in C:\app and loads an assembly at run time from C:\bin\assembly1.dll, 'assembly1.dll' has dependencies to 'assembly2.dll' and 'assembly3.dll' both of which are located in C:\bin, is there a way to make sure C:\bin\assembly1.dll can load its two dependencies in the same directory?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how `c:\bin\assembly1.dll` is loaded.  If you are using the `Assembly.LoadFrom` method then that should be enough.  The `LoadFrom` method will add the directory targeted to the hints list of the loader.  From then on it will probe that directory for resolving DLL dependencies.

The process for assembly loading and dependency probing is quite complex.  There is a rather large tutorial on MSDN which covers the details.  Section 4 is probably of most interest to you

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720659.aspx